# Using a instance method defined in model in my controller

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I'm running into the following error trying to use Sequelize and Typescript, both of which I am pretty new to:

```
(node:17276) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: week.calculateDays is not a function
```

I have the following in my controller which is being used by my route:

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import models from "../models";

export class Weeks {
  public static calculateDays = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    console.log(req.params);
    await models.Week.findByPk(req.params.id).then(week => {
      if (week) {
        console.log("Week found:", week);
        week.calculateDays();
      }
    });
  };
}
```

and defined the following in the model:

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";
import { SequelizeAttributes } from "../typings/SequelizeAttributes";
import { WeekAttributes } from "../interfaces/attributes";
import { WeekInstance } from "../interfaces/instances";
import models from "../models";
import { SessionAttributes } from "./sessions";

export const WeekFactory = (
  sequelize: Sequelize.Sequelize,
  DataTypes: Sequelize.DataTypes
): Sequelize.Model<WeekInstance, WeekAttributes> => {
  const attributes: SequelizeAttributes<WeekAttributes> = {
    ....attributes of the model....
  };

  const Week = sequelize.define<WeekInstance, WeekAttributes>(
    "weeks",
    attributes,
    {
      instanceMethods: {
        calculateDays: async function (this: WeekInstance) {
          console.log("Inside class method calculateDays");
          return await calculateDays(this.id!);
        }
      }
    }
  );

  const calculateDays = async (weekId: number) => {
      .......
  }
  return Week;
};
```

I'd really appreciate any kind of direction because I am not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the problem is the way you declared the `calculateDays` method. This should not receive the `WeekInstance` argument and you can use `this` normally inside the function. Also, I suggest to not use the same name for the out function `calculateDays`. I believe it is not reachable from inside the instance method and it is a little bit confusing, so I renamed it to `calculateDaysForWeek`

```
instanceMethods: {
    calculateDays: async function () {
      console.log("Inside class method calculateDays");
      return await calculateDaysForWeek(this.id!);
    }
  }
```

Good reference on how to create instance methods: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9760

Comment: When I omit it I get this error: ```Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Object'.ts(2339)```. From what I understand this is just a placeholder for the typescript.

Comment: So it might be my version (4.27.11) but I found that the link you provided linked to another gist which seems to have solved my problem: https://gist.github.com/evfleet/810cc5f463f70c04e1ecb321ee30466e